# retrieve data in using jQuery ajax function

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

hi friends i am working on CI and i want to get data from controller using jQuery ajax function..

this is my view

```
<select class="form-control" name="course" id="course">
                <option>Degree program</option>
                <option value="intermediate">Intermediate</option>
                <option value="bachelor">bachelor</option>
                <option value="master">master</option>
            </select>
```

this is my ajax functtion in jquery

```
$('#course').change(function(){

        var course = $('#course').val();

        $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo site_url('apply/course_list'); ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    course:course,
                },
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data)
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert('something wrong..')
                }


            });


    });
```

here is my controller

```
public function course_list(){
    $this->load->model('mod_apply');
    $course = $this->input->post('course');
      return $data['query'] = $this->mod_apply->course_list($course);



}
```

and this is my model

```
public function course_list($course){


        return $this->db->get($course);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `echo` instead of `return` and pass result as json.

```
public function course_list(){
 $this->load->model('mod_apply');
 $course = $this->input->post('course');
 $data['query'] = $this->mod_apply->course_list($course);
 echo json_encode($data);
}
```

ajax functtion

```
$('#course').change(function(){

    var course = $('#course').val();

    $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url('apply/course_list'); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                course:course,
            },
            success:function(data){
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(obj.yourfield);
            },
            error:function(){
                alert('something wrong..')
            }


        });

 });
```

Check [JSON.parse()](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp)

Comment: i know the basic concept of ajax function in jqurey but in the example i am getting data in array form not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the content type in your controller method.

Change
echo $data['query'] = $this->mod_apply->course_list($course);

To 
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('data'=>$this->mod_apply->course_list($course));

Answer (score 0):

i have got your issue
you are not posting data accurately
instead of

```
$.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo site_url('apply/course_list'); ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    course:course,
                },
```

Try

```
$.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo site_url('apply/course_list'); ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    "course":course
                },
```

and bingo